# SetDropDups() does not drop the duplicate indexes

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to create indexes for a specific field(Tracking Number) of my documents in MoongoDB. I do not want to insert duplicate values to my DB and want to drop the indexes that are duplicate. My code looks like the following but it does not work. When I try to insert a duplicate value, it gives me an error instead of dropping that index.

```
var keys = IndexKeys.Ascending("TrackingNumber");
var options = IndexOptions.SetUnique(true).SetDropDups(true);
_collection.CreateIndex(keys, options);
```

I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'MongoDB.Driver.MongoDuplicateKeyException occurred in
>   MongoDB.Driver.dll
>
> Additional information: WriteConcern detected an error. (Response was
>   { "ok" : 1, "code" : 11000, "err" : "insertDocument :: caused by ::
>   11000 E11000 duplicate key error index:
>   FedEx.FedExCollection2.$TrackingNumber_1  dup key: { : null }", "n" :
>   NumberLong(0) })

Can somebody help me solve the problem?

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you include the entire error message in your question.  Also consider telling us the database schema or whatever MongoDB uses.

Comment: Don't post it as a comment, edit it into your question.

Comment: Are you saying that the index was created without errors but when you then try and insert a doc with a duplicate `TrackingNumber` you're not expecting an error?

Comment: The question is: for the CreateIndex() method, if I try to insert a duplicate, should it give me an exception or it just ignores the duplicate insert?

Comment: A unique index will return a duplicate key error when you try to insert a duplicate key. It will not just ignore the document with the duplicate key.

Comment: Thanks, So how can I just ignore the duplicate keys without getting an exception error?

Comment: @Shary You can't. The dropDups option only applies during the creation of the index, not after.